# Derivation of pressure using partition function

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative

expression for the pressure due to a molecule in state number $i$
$$P_{i}=-\frac{d \varepsilon_{i}}{d V}$$

To find pressure

$$\begin{aligned}
P=\frac{N}{z} \sum_{i} P_{i} e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T} &=-\frac{N}{z} \sum_{i}\left(\frac{d \varepsilon_{i}}{d V}\right) e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T} \\
&=\frac{N k_{\mathrm{B}} T}{x} \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial V} e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}\right)_{T} \quad \text{Eq.1}
\end{aligned}$$

I dont understand how you come to the second line from the first line of Eq.1. I know there is somehow $\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon_{i} } e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}$. A step by step derivation from 1st line to second line would be really helpful

Comment: You might get more context at Physics.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just chain rule, $\varepsilon_i$ is a function of $V$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial V} (e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}) =  - \frac{1} {k_{\mathrm{B}} T}e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}\left(\frac{d \varepsilon_{i}}{d V}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
 - e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}\left(\frac{d \varepsilon_{i}}{d V}\right) =  k_{\mathrm{B}} T \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial V} (e^{-\varepsilon_{i} / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}) \right)
\end{aligned}.$$